# Listen for input in a hidden input-field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way, on document ready / page load, one can listen for more than three characters being typed in a row that don't do anything else, while nothing else is focused, and if that event occurs transfer those three characters and anything else that is typed after into an input-field of type text / search that is hidden — either by the display, visibility, or opacity CSS properties?

I would appreciate any help in doing this.

I have done something like this with a label and radio-button / check-box that is hidden. But that is because the input is just a click on the label. Not as complex as alpha-numeric input.

If you can help me with any part of achieving the above, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you need http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: The event is possible but I think exactly what you want isn't very clear. "Listen for more than 3 characters being typed in a row that don't do anything else, while nothing else is focused...?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be straight forward:

```
var keys = [];

$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    keys.push( String.fromCharCode(e.which) );
    if (keys.length > 2) 
        $('input').fadeIn(400).val( keys.join('') );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/afAc6/3/)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was aiming for. Except, I changed and updated the fiddle so that the input is focused and then the user can continue typing or submit by hitting enter / return. But now that I added the .focus, for some reason an extra copy of the third character is added.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @IMUXIxD - could use a little cleanup I suppose, like removing the event handlers if the limit is reached etc. Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/afAc6/19/) ??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but what you could do is call `.focus()` on the input whenever any other input has the event `onblur` and use the `oninput` event for your hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind keypress to the document and store the result in a variable until you're ready, something like:

```
var typedString = "";
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    typedString += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if(typedString.length >= 3){
        $('#some-textbox').show();
        $('#some-textbox').val(typedString);
    }
});
```